# Show that the root of $x^{1/3}=1-x$ lies between $0$ and $1$ using the intermediate value theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently doing a problem that asks me to use the intermediate value theorem to show that $x^{1/3}=1-x$ lies between $0$ and $1$. I want to start by evaluating the function at $0$ and $1$, but it seems the function is undefined because if you plug in $1$, you get $1=0$. This doesn't seem right. Is my interpretation correct?

The problem comes from Stewart's Calculus section 2.5, q 48.

Comment: Your function of consideration must be $f(x)=x^{1/3}-(1-x)$, for instance. $x^{1/3}=1-x$ is NOT a function, it is an equation

Comment: So, you can create a function out of an equation that doesn't make sense (i.e. where the LHS does not equal the RHS?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $f(x)=x^{1/3}-1+x$. Now $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to make the function work for these purposes now, but how is it equivalent to the original equation if I get different answers from the original when I plug in 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, you should think of the original equation as having a question mark: $x^{1/3}\overset{?}=1-x$ or $x^{1/3}-1+x\overset{?}=0$. Then we define for simplicity only (no other reason) $f(x)=x^{1/3}-1+x$ and we ask: for which $x$ is $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)\overset{?}=0$. Then we plug in two $x$'s which are easy to evaluate and give different sign to $f$. If the notation $f$ confuses you, you can ignore it. But keep in mind to interpret the given equation with a question mark. The exercise "asks" you to find $x$ so that this equation is fulfilled. It does not say that it is true for every $x$!

Answer (score 0):

Or: at $0$ LHS $= 0 < 1 =$ RHS, while at $1$, LHS $=1 > 0 =$ RHS, so at some $x$ between $0$ and $1$ the two sides have to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of solving equations with functions goes back to Descartes; instead of solving $f(x)=g(x)$, you can define
$$
F(x)=f(x)-g(x)
$$
and find the points where $F$ vanishes. In your case,
$$
F(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}+x-1
$$
Now
$$
F'(x)=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}+1
$$
is not defined for $x=0$ and it is strictly positive for $x\ne0$. Therefore $F$ is strictly increasing (note $F$ is continuous also at $0$).

Since $F(0)=-1$ and $F(1)=1$, we know that $F$ must vanish at a unique point in $(0,1)$.

---

You can also consider the equivalent equation
$$
x=(1-x)^3
$$
that translates to the function
$$
G(x)=x^3-3x^2+4x-1
$$
The derivative is
$$
G'(x)=3x^2-6x+4
$$
which is everywhere positive (the polynomial has no real roots). So $G$ is increasing and, since $G(0)=-1$ and $G(1)=1$, we have the same conclusion as before.